# Glass Mapper problem with solution upgraded from Sitecore 8.1 to 8.2

Tags: glass-mapper

We have updated our base solution which just contains a few example renderings from Sitecore 8.1 to 8.2. Note: we are still using VS 2013, but I don't think this should be any problem?

I have updated the references and I think I've tried just about everything in terms of removing and re-adding references, deleting readding and updating Nuget packages.

In my Views whenever I use Glass Mapper editable e.g.

```
@Editable(Model.DataItemModel, x=>x.HeaderText)
```

I'm getting `x=>x.HeaderText` underlined with this error:

```
Error   4   Cannot convert lambda expression to type
'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Project.Entities.HeaderSettings,object>>'
because it is not a delegate
type    c:\Projects\SitecoreMVC\Code\SitecoreMVC\Project.Web\Views\Shared\_Header.cshtml
```

I can't figure out what has changed. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you also upgrade Glass.Mapper to the newest version?

Comment: Yep version 4.2.1.190

Comment: Could you compare the contents of your `/Views/Web.config` and `/Areas/*/Views/Web.config` to the default `/Views/Web.config` that comes with Sitecore 8.2? They should be (in most cases) identical.

Comment: Yeah it is identical because I used the one that comes with 8.2
This is still driving me bonkers

Comment: @DaveBeta Is this a problem only in Visual Studio? Do the pages actually work correctly? Have you tried restarting Visual Studio? ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error (as well as many other errors) happens because of a mismatch between the used and the targeted versions of ASP.NET MVC binaries.

Sitecore 8.2 uses version **`5.2.3.0`** of the following assemblies:

- System.Web.Mvc
- System.Web.Http
- System.Web.Http.WebHost
- System.Net.Http.Formatting
- System.Web.Http.Cors

You need to make sure that you have the version **`5.2.3.0`** of these assemblies:

- for corresponding DLLs residing in your `bin` folder
- in ***Web.config*** under `configuration` > `system.web` > `compilation` > `assemblies`
- in the redirects in ***Web.config*** under `configuration` > `runtime` > `assemblyBinding`, for example:

  ```
  <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  ```
- in installed NuGet packages
- in references of all of your Sitecore projects
- in ***Web.config*** files (if you have any) under `/Views` and `/Areas/*/Views`, for example:

  ```
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

  ...

  <pages
      validateRequest="false"
      pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
      pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
      userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
    <controls>
      <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
    </controls>
  </pages>
  ```

You also need to ensure that the target framework in all of your projects, as well as in ***Web.config***, is set to **`4.5.2`**.

The error should be fixed after you perform the steps above.

Comment: I'm still double checking, but I don't think this is the problem. The issue appears to be related to Linq. I noticed Linq expressions such as Any aren't working in Views!

@if (Model.DataItemModel.CommentFolder.Comments.Any())
  
  
Error 6 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Project.Entities.Comment>' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Project.Entities.Comment>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @DaveBeta OK, that sounds like a completely separate problem. Make sure that you either have `@using System.Linq` in your view, of `<add namespace="System.Linq" />` in your `/Views/Web.config` under `system.web.webPages.razor` > `pages` > `namespace`.

Comment: If I add @using System.Linq it underlines Linq does not exist

Comment: Linq works fine in a controller though